# Download a pdf and save to device (ios and android) in react-native

Tags: react-native, pdf, react-native-fs, rn-fetch-blob

I am pretty new to react-native (app development as such). 
I want to download and save a pdf file in user's device in react-native? react-native-fs and rn-fetch-blob showed up as popular options.

I am using redux-saga in my project and axios to fetch json data. 
I am able to get a blob object of the pdf file using axios.

So, how can i achieve this downloading and saving the file in the device? Can i use axios plus some library to get the file from blob object or should i be using either react-native-fs or rn-fetch-blob?

Any suggestions would help!